# Get the single returned value with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

For this query:
`$sql='select col from table where other_col=?';`

I am currently getting the returned data like so:
`$data=$statement->fetch()['col'];`

That doesn't look very good to me.
Is there a better way of doing that or is that fine as it is?

Comment: If you have PHP 5.4 and can use that type of dereferencing `()[]` (and won't have to worry about backward compatibility when you deploy to other servers), use it. It's a great syntax improvement for PHP

Comment: Hey, I don't get it. Isn't that what I'm doing above? `fetch()` returns an array and I'm using `['col']` to get the `col` key.

Comment: Yes, that's what you're doing above. I'm saying you are already using an efficient and elegant method. Stick with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try :

```
$data=$statement->fetchColumn(0);
```

Comment: quick and simple answer. Recommended.